# HC-06 Bluetooth to Android - Receiving Random Symbols

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, app-inventor

I wanted to send values from a light sensor, using an HC-06. I have everything connected properly. I used MIT App Inventor and the image shows how I connect to the Bluetooth module, and how do I show the data.

[image]

**Arduino Code**

```
int analogInPin = A0;  
int sensorValue = 0;        

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(100);
}
```

**Phone**

[image]

I already searched for several solutions but none worked. I have the baud rate at 9600 (the same as the Bluetooth module).

Comment: Two things: (1) the code does what you want. (2) the 100 ms delay is way too little. It spams the buffer. Consider setting a delay of 5 to 10 seconds (5000 to 10000 ms) or so.

Comment: @dda I think you should add more information here. otherwise you might leave the impression that you can only properly transmit 3 characters per 5-10 seconds which is non-sense.

Comment: But the problem is: if I want to know if, during a couple of seconds, there was a change in the light (only for a couple of seconds), I want to have that change on Android so I can use the data to issue a notification (for example). Having a delay of 5 or 10 seconds could miss those changes.

Comment: what timer interval do you use for reading on the Android side? sending and receiving 10 values a second shouldn't be any problem as long as you make sure you empty your receive buffer quick enough

Comment: I have 100, bought in the timer and in the Arduino code.

Comment: both* - I already changed and the error is now "less" frequent. I used a character to mark the beginning of the values and it seems to work fine. Also, I added a statement to only print if the value's length is between 1 and 5.